# How do I keep a large directory that is located inside WSL2, in sync with another one in Windows?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, wsl2

I am using WSL2 with all my project files inside the Linux filesystem for better performance.

However, I want to backup that folder continuously into my Windows, just in case something happens to the VM or I just want direct access to that folder through Windows.

I tried using `rsync` but it keeps going through every single project and directory each run, taking ~20 - ~30 mins. every time. The projects directory is 2GB big.

Am I overlooking something? What if I just `cp` it with a cronjob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of rsync try using `robocopy` on Windows.  It's much faster to sync at roughly 10k files / second for incremental sync . The example is about 200MB in size. Id estimate you can complete in 20s

```
$logfile="$HOME\backup-wsl.log.txt"
$src="\\wsl.localhost\Debian\home\${env:Username}\sotion"
$dest=$(Join-Path ${env:OneDrive} "Documents\Sotion")
robocopy $src $dest /W:1 /R:0 /E /xd node_modules  /NFL /NDL /LOG+:$logfile
```

You can run this as a Scheduled Task

```
$time = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 2pm 
$user = (whoami)
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "${env:ProgramFiles}\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -Argument "-noninteractive -nologo -noprofile $HOME\scripts\backup-wsl\backup-wsl.ps1"
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Backup-WSL" -Trigger $Time -User $User -Action $action
```

Here's a [complete guide I wrote with some improved monitoring & error checking](https://tonym.us/wsl2-backup-to-onedrive-cloud.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, this is way better than using rsync altogether!

Comment: Glad you like it. I’ve found using windows tools will usually perform better .

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your rsync flags ([man rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync))

`rsync -hvrPt` (found in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67539/how-to-rsync-only-new-files)) may be suitable for your purposes

Using `cp` will work but tools like rsync are made with the purpose of backing up in mind, and typically speed things up if you configure them right (for example, only syncing files that have been modified).

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying it right now and rsync seems to go through each file(I think it's gonna take like 10-15 minutes), and saying "... is uptodate". Is it normal that it's doing this and taking this long?

Answer (score -1):

Well, wsl2's big downside compared to wsl1 is it's cross-OS file system performance. So there are still guides out there that tell you to do cross-OS file system work that shouldn't be done using wsl2.That's why they recommend keeping everything you do with wsl2 inside it's file system.
A file search command test that I performed targeting Windows file system, that took 4 sec using powershell and git bash, took 64 sec running it from wsl2.

Maybe use rsync or borg inside wsl2 for the backup solution (accidentally deleted files and so on), and then do a complete wsl2 backup `wsl --export DISTRO-NAME PATH\FILE-NAME.tar` for complete image backups